# Google pagespeed and image_rewrite for direct requests

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I have successfully installed Google pagespeed (it took me a while to get it up and running with nginx). 
I'm using Meteor as my framework and would like to use image_rewrite. The thing with Meteor is that the HTML gets rendered on the client. Obviously the typical scenario  will never pass by pagespeed, meaning pagespeed cannot optimize the page.

What I would like to do is that pagespeed optimizes the image on the http call for that image, but for some reason this does not work. Example:

If i open http://mydomain.com/myimage.jpg in the browser that image should be "pagespeeded" by all the filters that are active.  Unfortunately this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to turn on [InPlaceResourceOptization](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#ipro):

```
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
```